# td font size 18px looks like bold?

Tags: html, css, fonts, html-table, webfonts

I change the `td` font size to 18px , but it looks like bold? How can I fix this?

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" style="color: #000000;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;font-weight: normal;font-size: 18px;line-height: 27px;text-decoration:none;padding: 33px 91px 10px 91px;letter-spacing: 1px;border-left:1px solid #d2d2d2;border-right:1px solid #d2d2d2;">
      Oops, This Page Could Not Be Found!
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" style="color: #000000; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 18px; line-height: 18px; text-decoration:none; padding: 28px 0 41px 0; letter-spacing: 1px;border-left:1px solid #d2d2d2;border-right:1px solid #d2d2d2;">
      Oops, This Page Could Not Be Found!<a style="color:#7D7D7D;text-decoration:none;">Oops, This Page Could Not Be Found!</a>Oops, This Page Could Not Be Found!
      <a style="color:#7D7D7D;text-decoration:none;">Oops, This Page Could Not Be Found!</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please ask the question clearly.

Comment: It helps if you share codepen but for your question, it will help if you add font-weight: normal to td. Sometimes default css that is stored in browser, gives you unexpected results. Also i suggest you to use css files for your styles instead of writing css styles in html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of solving it. Firstly, you could reduce the weight of the font in your css

```
td {
 font-size: size px;
 use font weight
}
```

or

- you could change your font that does not look bold as sometimes it is because of the font being used it looks its bold but it is not bold.

or

- you might have put the font in `<strong></strong>` tag that might have put a bold effect over it.

Comment: @halfer - Thank you very much for letting me know. I am still learning on how to answer here. You help is much appreciated

Comment: No worries. It's a good answer, but there's no need to ask for code here (in a comment under the question is better). You are quite right, but in our experience, posts tend to be left like that when a question asker does not respond. We'd rather have posts written in a way they can be left in.

Comment: I used 18px for td, but it looks like bold, i doesn't want it looks like this.

Comment: @echochen - try using lighter in font-weight, or try changing the font from Arial to Something thin and for that look at https://fonts.google.com/  They have good fonts and they have styling and how to use in css as well. It would be better to use some good quality font if you are making a personal or professional website as these are UI changes which make the website look good. Good luck and let me know if you need help with anything more

Comment: Thank your very much! I used other fonts for it and this issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Change the font weight of your TD's to a specific number of your choice (100, 200, 300 etc.) and see what is the best for your design like the following example:

td {font-weight: 200;}

Comment: i used "font-weight:300!important;" for it . but it is also void.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `font-weight` property.

```
td{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

More information about font-weight here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp

Maybe a class override your td so you have to use.

```
td{
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: normal!important;
    }
```

But please note that use !important is not a good practice but an hard fix.  If you provide your .css code I can help you more further.